# How to eager load the Query

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, fluent-nhibernate

I'm facing with a `select N+1 issue` with the following Query. I'm new to `NHibernate`. Can anybody help me resolve this query in `NHibernate using Eager loading`.

```
public IList<MasterForecastInputSourceMatch> GetMasterForecastInputSourceMatchInfo(Guid elementId)
{
        var selectQuery = _session.CreateQuery("from MasterForecastInputSourceMatch where ElementInputInfo.Id = :id")
            .SetParameter("id", elementId);
        return selectQuery.List<MasterForecastInputSourceMatch>();
}
```

This is the Query generated. I used NHibernate Profiler

```
select masterfore0_.Id                    as Id88_,
   masterfore0_.UpdateDate            as UpdateDate88_,
   masterfore0_.MasterForecastInfo_id as MasterFo3_88_,
   masterfore0_.ElementInputInfo_id   as ElementI4_88_
   from   [PATH_MasterForecastInputSourceMatch] masterfore0_
   where  masterfore0_.ElementInputInfo_id = 'c414e888-cb9b-4c11-a52d-9fcd00a05ba4'
```

Comment: This query takes 4-5 seconds to execute in NHibernate while the same query execute in less than a second in SQL Server Managemnt Studio

Comment: In `ShowSql` output, which SQL is being generated?

Comment: which child collections of `MasterForecastInputSourceMatch` are you need?